# Eventually stopping a bouncing ball

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Creating a simple HTML5 Canvas program where there is an array of `balls` and each one moves at its own velocity and bounces against the canvas's 'walls'. I've also added gravity and friction by adding to the ball's `vy` and multiplying the `vx` and `vy` by a fraction of one, respectively.

For the `bounce`, I used a value of -0.7 so the ball loses a bit of energy on each bounce, but the problem is... it never completely 'stops'. It does a kind of 'bobbing' motion on the bottom of the map. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/rdso9fsk/25/).

Here is the code that checks the boundaries...

`checkBounds(ball, map, -0.7);`

(note: checkBounds is defined in utils.js)

```
function checkBounds(obj, map, bounce) {
  bounce = bounce || -1;
  var offset = {
    x: obj.width / 2 || obj.radius,
    y: obj.height / 2 || obj.radius
  };
  var bounds = {
    left: map.left || 0,
    right: map.right || map.width || innerWidth,
    top: map.top || 0,
    bottom: map.bottom || map.height || innerHeight
  }
  if (obj.x - offset.x < bounds.left) {
    obj.x = offset.x;
    obj.vx *= bounce;
  } else if (obj.x + offset.x > bounds.right) {
    obj.x = bounds.right - offset.x;
    obj.vx *= bounce;
  }
  if (obj.y - offset.y < bounds.top) {
    obj.y = offset.y;
    obj.vy *= bounce;
  } else if (obj.y + offset.y > bounds.bottom) {
    obj.y = bounds.bottom - offset.y;
    obj.vy *= bounce;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

How would I make the ball ease into a stop at some point?

Comment: You mention gravity and that the balls wobble at the bottom specifically (which seems to hint at an issue with gravity), but the code fragment doesn't seem to take gravity into account?

Comment: Can you put your code in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), and link it in the question?

Comment: If the velocity is below some sufficiently small epsilon value (like one pixel per frame), then stop its motion instead of reversing it.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited in the link to the fiddle.